# Unresolved External Symbol calling inherited class function

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, unresolved-external

I'm trying to have a class call a function from an inherited class however whenever I do I get an unresolved external error `LNK2019`. I'm confused to why this is happening as all of the files appear to be properly included, I haven't overridden the function & Visual Studio doesn't complain about it prior to compiling.

I've tried:

- Running the replacing the function call with the actual code, this fixes one of the two errors but I still get an unresolved external as the functions in question are calling another function from another class.
- Messing around with namespaces, as the inherited class is under a separate namespace I thought that was the problem e.g. `Memory::Allocate(...)`.
- Directly calling the class function, so instead of `Allocate(...)` I tried `Memory::GlobalMemoryUser::Allocate(...)`
- Calling the function using `this->...`

Relevant code from *GlobalMemoryUser.h*

```
#include "MemoryManager"

namespace Memory
{
    namespace Internal
    {
        extern MemoryManager* GlobalMemoryManager;
    {

    class GlobalMemoryUser
    {
    public:

        // Allocator and deallocator
        inline const void* Allocate(size_t, const char* user);
        inline const void DeAllocate(void*);

    private:

        // A pointer to the global memory manager
        Internal::MemoryManager* GlobalMemoryManager;
    };
}
```

Relevant code from *GlobalMemoryManager.cpp*

```
#include "GlobalMemoryUser.h"

namespace Memory {

    const void* GlobalMemoryUser::Allocate(size_t size, const char* user)
    {
        return GlobalMemoryManager->Allocate(size, user);
    }

    const void GlobalMemoryUser::DeAllocate(void* p)
    {
        GlobalMemoryManager->DeAllocate(p);
    }
}
```

Relevant code from *System Manager.h*

```
#include "GlobalMemoryUser.h"

namespace ECS
{
    class SystemManager : public Memory::GlobalMemoryUser
    {
        // Constructor and Deconstructor
        SystemManager();
        ~SystemManager();
    };
}
```

Relevant code from *SystemManager.cpp*

```
#include "SystemManager.h"

namespace ECS
{
    SystemManager::SystemManager()
    {
        systemAllocator = new Memory::LinearAllocator(ECS_SYSTEM_MEMORYBUFFERSIZE, Allocate(ECS_SYSTEM_MEMORYBUFFERSIZE, "SystemManager"));
    }


    SystemManager::~SystemManager()
    {
        for (std::vector<ISystem*>::reverse_iterator it = systemWorkOrder.rbegin(); it != systemWorkOrder.rend(); it++)
        {
            (*it)->~ISystem();
            *it = nullptr;
        }

        systemWorkOrder.clear();
        systemsTable.clear();

        DeAllocate((void*)systemAllocator->GetUsedMemoryStart());
        delete systemAllocator;
        systemAllocator = nullptr;
    }
}
```

The errors in question happen within the constructor and deconstructor for the system manager when trying to call the allocator and deallocator from the GlobalMemoryUser parent class.

Exact Error Message:
`LNK2019  unresolved external symbol "public: void const * __cdecl Memory::GlobalMemoryUser::Allocate(unsigned __int64,char const *)" (?Allocate@GlobalMemoryUser@Memory@@QEAAPEBX_KPEBD@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl ECS::SystemManager::SystemManager(void)" (??0SystemManager@ECS@@QEAA@XZ)`

Comment: What is the error message exactly?

Comment: please edit the error message into your question

Comment: Is this your exact code? It wouldn't appear to compile due to mismatched braces

Comment: Do `SystemManager` and `GlobalMemoryUser` belong to the same module?

Comment: It is not the exact code, I cut out quite a bit that wasn't relevant to the question although I don't see where the mismatched braces are could you tell me where they are?

Comment: Also what do you mean by Module?

Comment: BTW, is `ECS_SYSTEM_MEMORYBUFFERSIZE` of the same type as `size_t`?

Comment: Yes ```ECS_SYSTEM_MEMORYBUFFERSIZE``` is of the same type.

Comment: Did your code compile and still reproduce your problem after you edited it? Please post a [mre]

Comment: How `ECS_SYSTEM_MEMORYBUFFERSIZE` is declared?

Comment: Remove the `inline` keywords. They do not belong there since they require the function to be defined in the header. See linked duplicates.

Comment: ```ECS_SYSTEM_MEMORYBUFFERSIZE``` is a macro defined in another included file.